What is the best low-risk, short-term(3-month) option to invest 50K?
I currently have $50,000 in cash and am looking for a safe, low-risk place to invest it for a 3-month period. My main priority is to avoid any options that have a risk of losing money, as I want to preserve my capital.
=
Thank you in advance for your help!

What country are you in? May impact the options available to you.

A high-yield savings account, promotional-rate certificate of deposit, or a money market account.
Higher returns involve higher risk, which you have said you don't want.

A 3-month CD or a savings account would be the only thing that would be guaranteed not to lose money.
Given that 3-month CD rates are currently between 2 and 4% annualized, you're looking at 0.5% - 1% overall interest, or $250 - $500 over 3 months.
Even "fixed income" investments like bonds and Bond ETFs carry some risk of loss.

I've had the same question, and from what others said, short term government bonds are very safe, such as SGOV. Decent yield and is very safe.

I would add that you can also buy them outright via TreasuryDirect or your brokerage account
